formatting mismatch for PaddleOCR
Currently, I am working on an OCR project where I need to read text from an invoice (see sample image below). I am having issues with the image skew and also the output format I am getting, I need help to fix the image skew so that the text is horizontal and not slanted as well as the output, I want the output format to be the same as the original document. Initially I tried the box helper format to print the text in the box so that the structure is the same, but because there is a slanted file, the format creates new problems when I extract it with fuzzywuzzy. Currently I need some resources or suggestions to solve my problem.
code:
# Class FieldReader with fuzzy matching and flexible prefix matching
class FieldReader:
    def __init__(self, field_name, keywords, prefix=None, default="-", threshold=60):
        self.field_name = field_name
        self.keywords = keywords
        self.prefix = prefix  
        self.default = default
        self.threshold = threshold

    def extract(self, text):
        words = text.split()
        potential_value = None

        for keyword in self.keywords:
            # Use fuzzy matching to find the best match for the keyword in the text
            best_match = process.extractOne(keyword.rstrip(':'), words, scorer=fuzz.partial_ratio)
            if best_match and best_match[1] >= self.threshold:
                index = words.index(best_match[0])

                # Search for the ":" in the following words
                for i in range(index + 1, len(words)):
                    if ":" in words[i]:
                        # If found, remove anything between keyword and ":" (clean unwanted characters)
                        if i > index + 1:
                            words[index + 1:i] = []  # Remove intermediate words between keyword and ":"

                        # Extract the word immediately following the ":"
                        if i + 1 < len(words):
                            potential_value = words[i + 1]
                        else:
                            potential_value = None
                        break

                # If a prefix is defined, check if the value starts with that prefix (without specifying length)
                if self.prefix and potential_value and potential_value.startswith(self.prefix):
                    return potential_value  # Return the value if it starts with the prefix

                elif potential_value:
                    return potential_value  # Return the value if no prefix is specified or matches

        return self.default  # Return default value if no match is found



class FieldReader_regex:
    def __init__(self, field_name, pattern):
        self.field_name = field_name
        self.pattern = pattern

    def extract(self, text):
        # Mencari semua kecocokan dengan regex
        matches = re.findall(self.pattern, text)
        # Mengambil hanya hasil pertama atau mengembalikan '-' jika tidak ada
        return matches[0] if matches else "-"



# Function to extract information from text using fuzzy matching
def extract_information(text, provider):
    data = {}
    if provider == "Pertamina":
        patterns = [
            FieldReader("Date", ["Date", "Tanggal", "Issue Date"], default="-"),
            FieldReader_regex("Aircraft Reg", r"\bPK\w*\b"),  # Ambil semua yang berawalan PK untuk Aircraft Reg
            FieldReader_regex("Flight Numbers", r"\bQZ\w*\b"),  # Ambil semua yang berawalan QZ untuk nomor penerbangan
            # FieldReader("Reg", ["Reg", "Reg g", "Aircraft Reg","Aircraft Reg g", "Alrcraft Reg", "AIRCRAFT REG"], prefix="PK", default="-"),
            # FieldReader("Flight No", ["Flight Number", "Flight No", "Flight Nunber","Flight N0", "Fllght Number", "FLIGHT NUMBER"], prefix ="QZ", default="-"),
            FieldReader("Dep", ["IATA", "Departure", "Dep", "TATA", "lATA"], default="-"),
            FieldReader("Uplift_in_Lts", ["Quantity", "QUANTITY", "Fuel Quantity", "Uplift", "Quantity", "Delivered Volume (L)"], default="-"),
            FieldReader_regex("Invoice", r"DELIVERY RECEIPT\s*(\S+)"),
            FieldReader("Provider", ["Provider", "Supplier"], default="Pertamina")
        ]
    elif provider == "Shell":
        patterns = [
            FieldReader("Date", ["Date", "Issue Date"], default="-"),
            FieldReader("Reg", ["Reg", "Aircraft Reg"], default="-"),
            FieldReader("Flight No", ["Flight No"], default="-"),
            FieldReader("Dep", ["IATA", "Departure"], default="-"),
            FieldReader("Arr", ["Next Dest", "Arrival"], default="-"),
            FieldReader("Uplift_in_Lts", ["QUANTITY", "Fuel Quantity"], default="-"),
            FieldReader_regex("Aircraft Reg", r"\bPK\w*\b"),  # Ambil semua yang berawalan PK untuk Aircraft Reg
            FieldReader_regex("Invoice", r"DELIVERY RECEIPT\s*(\S+)"),
            FieldReader("Provider", ["Provider", "Supplier"], default="SHELL")
        ]

    for field in patterns:
        data[field.field_name] = field.extract(text)

    return data


# Function to preprocess the image (grayscale and threshold)
def preprocess_image(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    return thresh

# Function to draw boxes and extract text based on boxes with left-to-right order
def extract_text_by_boxes(result, image_width, margin=2):
    box_data = []
    box_counter = 1

    for line in result:
        for word_info in line:
            box = word_info[0]  # Coordinates of the box
            text, conf = word_info[1]  # Text and confidence

            # Get coordinates of the word box
            x_min, y_min = box[0]
            x_max, y_max = box[2]

            # Adjust box to cover the entire width of the image (left to right)
            extended_box = [[0, y_min - margin], [image_width, y_min - margin], [image_width, y_max + margin], [0, y_max + margin]]
            box_data.append((box_counter, extended_box, text))
            box_counter += 1

    return box_data

# Function to perform OCR based on bounding boxes
def ocr_boxes(processed_image, box_data):
    full_text = ""
    for box_info in box_data:
        box_counter, extended_box, _ = box_info

        # Create a mask for the bounding box
        mask = np.zeros_like(processed_image)
        cv2.fillPoly(mask, [np.array(extended_box).astype(np.int32)], (255,))

        # Extract the region of interest (ROI) using the mask
        roi = cv2.bitwise_and(processed_image, mask)

        # OCR the ROI without rotation
        ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en')
        result = ocr.ocr(roi, cls=True)

        # Concatenate the extracted text
        for line in result:
          if not line:  # This checks for None or empty list
                continue
          for word_info in line:
                text = word_info[1][0]
                full_text += f" {text}"

        # Draw the box for visualization
        cv2.polylines(processed_image, [np.array(extended_box).astype(np.int32)], isClosed=True, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
        cv2.putText(processed_image, str(box_counter), (int(extended_box[0][0]), int(extended_box[0][1] - 10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    return full_text

# Function to extract text from images with boxes and sort by box order
def getText(file_path):
    images = convert_from_path(file_path, dpi=300)
    full_text_all = ""

    for i, page in enumerate(images):
        page_array = np.array(page)
        page_array = cv2.cvtColor(page_array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # Apply preprocessing (optional)
        processed_image = preprocess_image(page_array)
        image_width = processed_image.shape[1]

        # OCR the processed image
        ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en')
        result = ocr.ocr(processed_image, cls=True)

        # Extract text using custom boxes
        box_data = extract_text_by_boxes(result, image_width, margin=0)

        # Sort box data by box order
        box_data.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

        # Perform OCR on each bounding box
        full_text = ocr_boxes(processed_image, box_data)
        full_text_all += full_text

        # Print the extracted text from the current image (for debugging)
        print(f"\nExtracted text from image {i + 1}:\n{full_text}")

        # Display the processed image with boxes
        cv2_imshow(processed_image)

        # Save the processed image (optional)
        cv2.imwrite(f"processed_page_{i+1}.png", processed_image)

    return full_text_all

example:
enter image description here
the output was not printed correctly and missmatch.
If anyone can help me figure this problem out, it would be of much help.

You may start with this OpenCV alignment tutorial: Image alignment and registration with OpenCV
